# How do I write this SQL query in MS Access to

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a list of records like so

```
ID---EffectiveDate---Rate
1----1/1/2011--------1.2
2----1/1/2012--------1.3
3----1/1/2013--------1.5
4----1/1/2014--------1.2
```

Given a date parameter, d1, I want to get the record with the latest effective date prior to d1.  So, if d1 = 6/1/2012, I want to get the second record.  How can I write a query like this in MS Access SQL?

Comment: If the pattern for effective date is quite rigid as shown in the sample data, why not just use  `WHERE Year(EffectiveDate) = Year(d1)`?

Answer (score 1):

I think the SQL query would looks something like this, based on your data:

```
SELECT TOP 1 EffectiveDate
FROM MyTableOfDates
WHERE EffectiveDate <= #MyInputDate#
ORDER BY EffectiveDate DESC
```

Comment: `ORDER BY EffectiveDate DESC`

Comment: Jeez that was simple.  I feel dumb for not thinking of it myself, haha.  Thanks!

Comment: Yup, misread that. Edited the answer to reflect @HansUp's correction.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
select top 1 * from tablename where EffectiveDate<=d1 order by EffectiveDate desc
```